# The Blog's Progress: Week One + 2 Days

Tags: discussion, blog

This post is supposed to exist two days before hence the plus two days... Anyway, this post and the tons more to come will cover the progress of the blog weekly. Graphs, pictures, captions, and information will be provided as well as the stories that came from that week that will soon be collected onto one archive-type meta post. Let's begin.

**Users**

Currently we have four editors (highest "rank" on the blog) which are me, fi12, Christophe Strobbe, and Hatchet. We could use more editors and writers (stories must be approved by editors) to help improve the status of the blog.

**Content**

We now have 5 new stories which help garner a whole lot more views:

- [Duolingo Overall Review](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/duolingo-73b5c6b00a5d#.qxx1fl0sm)
- [Interview With An Author: Anthony Pham](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/interview-with-an-author-anthony-pham-5229c86b34f6#.9k5drjwjo)
- [What is Language Learning Stack Exchange?](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/what-is-language-learning-stack-exchange-9d26450da3a3#.n00cph6qk)
- [Welcome to the Blog!](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/welcome-to-the-blog-74bbf30ebd4f#.swii2q24q)
- [Meet the Authors (and others)!](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/meet-the-authors-and-others-72cd5d37c1a8#.m8ilj0txp)

No, I cannot write all the stories so can everyone else please make stories as well. When I say stories, I mean the articles you read on the blog, not children's stories.

**Views, Reads, Visitors**

Our blog was seen 189 times ever since this post was written:

[image]

As you can see, the days the articles were published were the days the blog gets more activity. Thus, more artciles are needed. Our highest was on November 7 with 71 views when I published three new articles.

Our articles were read for 9 minutes... extremely little when you notice that the total estimated read time for all the articles is 13 minutes. This means all the reads were from the other users other than me reading the articles and apperently, we never got visitors:

[image]
[image]

**Updates to Blog**

Yes! I have redesigned the blog just a bit to organize the articles better and make the blog look more professional. This includes:

- Adding a background picture to the title block
- Adding a background color to all possible features Medium allows
- Creating tabs to organize the articles (the clcikable words that say Introductions, Language Learning SE, Languages, Authors, etc.)

The organization is based on tagging:

- Articles make it under the [Introductions](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/tagged/introduction) section if the article has the "Introduction" tag.
- Articles make it under the [Language Learning SE](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/tagged/llse) section if the article has the "Llse" tag.
- Articles make it under the [Languages](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/tagged/language) section if the article has the "Language" tag.
- Articles make it under the [Authors](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/tagged/authors) section if the article has the "Authors" tag.
- Articles make it under the [Language Software/Programs](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog/tagged/software) if the article has the "Software" tag.

Notice how there the tags have the first letters of the tag uppercased and the rest are lowercased. That is forced and the tag must be properly spelled and capitalized in order for the articles to go under the correct section. Otherwise, you can only find it back at the home page.

Second, there is this "LL.SE Home" tab with the other tabs even though it doesn't organize any of the articles. That tab is used to send those who click on it straight to the home page of our site so readers can check us out and hopefully become users.

**Summary**

We need more Medium writers and editors to create more articles so the blog gets more attention and views from people other than the actual authors. This creates more attention to our site and thus this site will be booming with activity.

Otherwise, we are cruising quite fine for the first week of launching. Good luck to everyone and I'll make the update next Friday (November 18).

Comment: I have added an ["interview" post](https://medium.com/@christophe_s/interview-with-an-llse-contributor-christophe-strobbe-42de7525dd0c). I'd replace "author" with "LLSE contributor", since "author" is misleading when read out of context.

Comment: What licence should the blog content have? I don't see a licence anywhere. Do the authors choose the licence for each individual article? BTW, Stack Exchange uses Creative Commons cc by-sa 3.0.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/483/concerning-the-licensing-of-content-on-the-blog