# Our shiny new blog needs contributors!

Tags: discussion, blog

As PythonMaster wrote [here](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/the-blogs-progress-week-one-2-days), our community blog has been launched and we've seen some great progress in the last week though. Unfortunately, we only have 4 active contributors out of a community of more than 1500 users. That needs to change; this is a community blog, so we'd love to see more active participation from users across the site. If you're interested in writing or editing for the blog (regardless of how inexperienced or new you are to LL), drop by the [LL blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47429/language-learning-blog) and ping me with your [Medium](http://medium.com) username. I'll add you and you can get started right away.

Happy blogging!

Comment: You should add what topics the blog is supposed to have so others know what to write once they're part of the blog

Comment: Second, who should be writers and who should be editors? FYI, writers can publish their stories once an editor approves of it (for example, if Hatchet is a writer, he must submit his draft but wait for an editor like me to officially publish it).

Comment: Third, these people should at least have *some* experience with the topics covered by the blog

Comment: @PythonMaster The topic is anything related to language learning; it isn't necessary for us to dictate exactly what you can write about on the blog.

Comment: @PythonMaster In terms of editors and writers, more experienced LL users should be editors while newer ones should be authors.

Comment: @PythonMaster I disagree that experience is required for *all* posts. In the case of an interview with a prominent polyglot, for example, not much language learning experience is required. Some research into the topic would be sufficient.

Comment: Sorry about that. When I say some, I literally mean some as in sufficient

Comment: Are any and all members of this community entitled to post on the blog, or are we going to have a ["Want to contribute?" post like Worldbuilding](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e) e.g. with an editorial "team" (of sorts) and an post review process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add username here under current format:

- Username for blog ([username for Language Learning SE](link to LL.SE profile))

For example:

- Anthony Pham ([PythonMaster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster))

**NOTE:** If someone requests for more information about your username on Medium because there are multiple names that match yours, supply your profile picture to the user that requested the information.

---

Start adding your usernames here (make a list!):